# How to store/edit Laravel translation files dynamicly and use it in Vue.js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-localization

I'm developping a Laravel/ Vue.js website and I want create an interface where users with `translator` account can access to this interface and add/edit values of content files `/lang/en...`  and then I can use this files in `vue.js` 
 
 I want ask how can I store or edit data in this config files ? or what is the alternative please ?

Comment: You could create a route that looks like a file. For example `/lang/{langCode}/messages.json`, which in reality is just a controller returning JSON. You could write cached results on the file system and rebuilt when translator changes are saved.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I write this route `Route::get('/js/lang.js', function () {
    $strings = Cache::rememberForever('lang.js', function () {
        $lang = config('app.locale');

        $file   = glob(base_path('lang/' . $lang . '.json'));
        $strings = [];
    
        $name        = basename($file, '.json');
        $strings[$name] = require $file;
        return $strings;
    });
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');  echo 'window.i18n=' . json_encode($strings) . ';'; exit();
})->name('assets.lang'); ` but it return `window.i18n = []; ` and I have content on local file

Comment: You can't `require` a json file. To read a json file, you should use `file_get_conents".
Also please update your question and add the code that you've tried.